# Caste ActiveRecord - LINQ optimised query

Tags: linq, nhibernate, c#-3.0, castle-activerecord

I use [Castle ActiveRecord](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/index.html) as my persistance layer.

I got this functions that must return the first 20 users from the database.

```
IList<User> users = new List<User>();

var userQuery = from u in User.FindAll()
                orderby u.CreationDate
                select u;

return userQuery.Take(20).ToList();
```

In my database, I currently have 100 users, I only want that my query return 20 users and not 100.

When I monitor what's happening with log4net, I see that the query first get 100 users and after, only take the 20 firsts.

I would like to know if it's there a better way of doing this. Because the more users I'll have, the more my query will be slow and not optimized...

Comment: I'm assuming the queries you're seeing here are first a query only retrieving id's and then the query to get the 20 entities?

Can you post the queries from log4net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what happens..

1. The method User.FindAll() returns an array of all users. (100 rows from the DB)
2. Then you order and filter that same array.

With [AR 2.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/castleproject/files/) you can use ActiveRecordLinqBase instead of ActiveRecordBase and use .Queryable instead if .FindAll().

This query will return only the 20 records from the database..

```
var userQuery = (from u in User.Queryable
                orderby u.CreationDate
                select u).Take(20).ToList();
```

Comment: it's seems to be exactly what I want! But now, I got this error : System.ObjectDisposedException: Session is closed! Any idea how I can solve that ?

Comment: Are you running your query inside a session-scope?
When using ActiveRecord.Linq a SessionScope is required.

using (new SessionScope()) { your Linq-code... }

Comment: Is there a way to define some sort of default Session-Scope ? Because I don't really like the idea to put a using that wrap all my linq-code..

Comment: If your're building a web-app you should check out the SessionScopeWebModule.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom HQL query which has a "SetMaxResults" method.  See the [ActiveRecord Users guide](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/trunk/usersguide/hql.html) for an example.